# Connect to exchange server with certifcate based on own CA-root?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, exchange, samsung-galaxy-s-plus

I am owning a galaxy s plus with the latest 2.3.6 firmware available for that phone.
I want to connect to my companies exchange-server. Our company has defined an ow CA. With this all user certificates are signed. 
Now I have tried to connect via active sync with my certificate to my exchange account. But always it tells me that, the user name or password is wrong. After writing it about 20 times I guess I have made no mistake while typing my password.

I have installed my certificate (including CA-certificate of our company) via Settings -> Security -> install certificates from sd.

Is there anything I can do?

On my colleages Samsung S2 (Android 4) there is an additional Option "use client certificates". This isn't available on Android 2.3.6. Is there any possibility to get my exchange account on my phone?